# Unable to open another link in androidwebview when javascript alert is on

Tags: android-webview

I am new to android gcm app development. Sorry in advance if am not clear in my question.

I have modified the GCM demo client program to display an alert when a message arrives. 
And up on click of OK in the alert it should open a different URL in my Webview.

example : My webview shows abc.com and and gcm message arrives which displays an alert and up on clicking OK it takes me to xyz.com, This works fine in normal case.

But Problem occurs when an alert a different alert is opened in abc.com view, which is not allowing me to open a different URL until that alert is closed.
**Is there a way to forcefully close the alert and open the new URL in the webview.**

Comment: I totally struck at this point :(
If anybody visited this page,Please let me know if the question need to be more clear.